# Does frames affect BHO javascript injection?

Tags: javascript, c#, c++, vb.net, internet-explorer

I'm making a BHO that exposes method to JavaScript. It works well on the first load of a page but if I navigate to another page in the same window, the BHO object become `null` and can't be accessed from javascript. The page I'm navigating to has multiple frames. Does frames affect BHO injections? What is a proper way to do it?

Here is the code I use to inject the window

```
OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
   {
        dynamic windowEx  = ((IHTMLDocument2)this.Browser.Document).parentWindow;

           IExpando windowEx = (IExpando)Window;

           if (windowEx.GetProperty("testBHO", BindingFlags.Default) == null)
           {
               PropertyInfo p = windowEx.AddProperty("testBHO");
               p.SetValue(windowEx, this,null);
           }
    }
```

Comment: how are you injecting this script into individual pages?

Comment: Injected scripts woks fine the problem is the BHO script object becomes null after navigating to another page. Anyways I use HTMLScriptElement script = (HTMLScriptElement)document.createElement("script");